# How to use openlayer in class in C#

Tags: c#, class, openlayers

I want to use the openlayers libary in my class "DeviceClass" so I do this:

```
  public class DeviceClass : OpenLayers.DeviceCollection.Device
  {
  }
```

Now I get the error that

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter c# class openlayers

and is

> Deviceclass underlind

. Can someone help?

The full code is:

```
namespace_klasses_met_openlayer
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DeviceClass d = new DeviceClass();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void btndevicename_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d.getname();
    }
}

public class DeviceClass : OpenLayers.DeviceCollection.Device
{
    // OpenLayers fields
    ////Encapsulates a DT-open layers deviceand manages and distributes subsystems for the device
    private Device device = null;

    // Manages DT-Open Layers devices
    private DeviceMgr deviceMgr = DeviceMgr.Get();


    public void getname()
    {
        // Get the device names of all devices in the system
        // Put into array of stings deviceNames
        string[] deviceNames = deviceMgr.GetDeviceNames();

        //Add deviceNames to combobox
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceNames.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(deviceNames[i]);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to use Openlayers directly in C#. A possible way in C# would be to use the WebBrowser Class [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.2) to load a HTML document using the openlayers library via JavaScript. The HTML document should run under the IE9 or IE10 emulation to render the HTML document correctly [see here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version).